# Why font awesome icon shows empty squares?

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I would like to make a combination of icons via FA stack but it does not work. I have pure example from documentation and it shows me only empty squares. Code looks like:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="fa-stack" style="vertical-align: top;">
     <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
     <i class="fas fa-flag fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span>
```

and the result looks like on the picture below (last icon on the line).
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the correct CDN which is the one of the V5 not the V4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css">

<span class="fa-stack" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-flag fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Yes version is wrong, but also this example dos not work. Still the same empty squares.

Comment: @Čamo you see empty square if you run the above snippet?

Comment: Sorry my bad. The part of my experiments was css code like `*:not(.fa) {
 font-family: Arial;
}` which caused this problem.